# Connecting one Trello card to two different boards

Tags: trello, links, sharing

Can you link a card in one board to another so you don't have to update information in two places?

Answer (score 8):

This is not possible right now, but it's something we're considering for the future. There are serious design challenges around doing this. Consider that users and labels might differ between the two boards. Visibility might even differ. It's not a small feature and we'd have to carefully consider the value added vs. other features we could add.